# User-defined template string

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

I'm looking for a way to give a user an option to define template literal. That template will be sent to backend and used with the data he provided.

Example scenario:

```
const dataSentToBackend = [
  {
    name: 'Adam',
    country: 'Spain'
  },{
    name: 'Eve',
    country: 'Germany'
  }
]
```

User wants to generate two files that are like that: `{name} from {country}` (or anything else that let's him use tags how he like). So files in this example would be named as `Adam from Spain` and `Eve from Germany`.

The trick is that template needs to be preserved as a template so it can be used when data is actually being processed at the backend. So it can be used in a loop that names files one by one by the `dataSentToBackend` array.

So far I only found `String.raw` function (thanks to [this](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_template-literals.html) page), but I didn't found it much helpful for me (or I didn't understood it).

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick, but wouldn't this depend more on your backend processing language? Or is that JavaScript as well?

Comment: It's JavaScript as well (Node + Express).

Comment: So, what have you tried? Seems like you don't even have to use the template literal syntax; you could make up your own syntax and use regex, as long as it's easy to parse.

Comment: As for now I'm looking where to start. I know that I need to send that template to backend and use it once it's there. The question is how to transport it so it will work and be safe (should I worry about XSS here?).

Comment: You want to allow the client to specify a string like `{name} from {country}` and have the server perform the substitution, right?  This seems reasonable.  I assume you **don't** want to allow all of JavaScript functionality in there too.  `{name} from {exec("rm -rf *")}` would be bad, right?  So you do NOT want JavaScript to be the string replacement mechanism, right?  `string.replace` should do the trick fairly safely.

Comment: Yes, yes, that's what I thought! I thought also about regular expression that will look for strings between `{` and `}` and use it as a key within data set and from here it would behave like typical Object property access. Will that be safe enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.  I used the regular expression `[a-z]+` for the property name which you could expand if you need to allow more characters (uppercase, underscores, numbers etc.)

```js
const dataSentToBackend = [
  {
    name: 'Adam',
    country: 'Spain'
  }, {
    name: 'Eve',
    country: 'Germany'
  }
]

const templateSentToBackend = "{name} from {country}";

serverSideReplace = (template, datas) =>
  datas.map(data => template.replace(/\{([a-z]+)\}/g, (_, key) => data[key]));

console.log(serverSideReplace(templateSentToBackend, dataSentToBackend));
```

Comment: A more comprehensive regex forgiving whitespace:  `/{\s*(\w+?)\s*}/g`

Comment: This is perfection. I used the regex from comment because it's more forgiving. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a regex that doesn't include the group if { is prefixed with \. For example, `\{one} {two}` two is only captured because there's no backslash. `/(?<!\\){\s*(\w+?)\s*}/g`

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the answer by Kamel to fix a couple issues.

```js
function format(template, data) {
    let result;
    result = template.replace(/(?<!\\){\s*(\w+?)\s*}/g, (_, key) => {
        if (data[key] != undefined) {
            return data[key];
        }
        return `{${key}}`;
    });
    result = result.replace(/(\\{\s*\w+?\s*})/g, (_, key) => {
        if (key[0] === ('\\')) {
            return key.substring(1);
        }
        return key;
    });
    return result;
}
```

The regex is different, it allows the user to escape the curly brackets. The second replace just removes the `\` before the ignored groups.

```js
format("\\{test} {test}", {test: "hi"}) // "{test} hi"
```

It fixes an issue where if a key didn't exist, it would add `undefined` to the string. It now just ignores undefined keys.

```js
format("{test} {tes}", {test: "hi"}) // "hi {tes}"
```

I also made it a bit more readable since it took me a while to figure out how it worked.

Here's a full example with what the OP wanted.

```js
function format(template, data) {
    let result;
    result = template.replace(/(?<!\\){\s*(\w+?)\s*}/g, (_, key) => {
        if (data[key] != undefined) {
            return data[key];
        }
        return `{${key}}`;
    });
    result = result.replace(/(\\{\s*\w+?\s*})/g, (_, key) => {
        if (key[0] === ('\\')) {
            return key.substring(1);
        }
        return key;
    });
    return result;
}

const dataSentToBackend = [
  {
    name: 'Adam',
    country: 'Spain'
  }, {
    name: 'Eve',
    country: 'Germany'
  }
]

const templateSentToBackend = "{name} from {country}";

function serverSideReplace(template, datas) {
    return datas.map(data => format(template, data));
}

console.log(serverSideReplace(templateSentToBackend, dataSentToBackend));
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your user is inputing is template string in an input field. You can simple save an escaped string in your database, and unescape the same before compiling it into template string.

And to actually use it back you can try something like this.

```
const templateString = "Hello ${this.name}!"; // replace it with unescaped template 
const templateVars = {
    name: "world"    
}

const fillTemplate = function(templateString, templateVars){
    return new Function("return `"+templateString +"`;").call(templateVars);
}

console.log(fillTemplate(templateString, templateVars));
```

But i would definitely say *don't* let user define templates and use it, unless you have a really solid sanitizing script.

Comment: Yes, assumption is correct. Escaping string like with `encodeURIComponent` of sorts?

Comment: @jeand'arme yes

Comment: I believe the `templateString` is intended to be user-provided, but server-side-executed right?  In which case, there is a **HUGE** risk of client side template strings like:  `${fs.unlinkSync('important.txt')}` or a string that starts with a backtick for a direct injection attack or even just an exception from invalid syntax like `\`@\``

Comment: @Wyck i did mention to not use this approach in the answer